# Quick question: Poincare dual class to the fundamental cycle of a submanifold

Tags: differential-geometry

$X$ is a compact, oriented $n$-manifold and $Y$ is a $k$-submanifold of $X$. Let $\eta_{Y}$ be the Poincare dual class to the fundamental cycle $[Y] \in H_{k}(X,\mathbb{Z})$ and $\phi \in H^{k}_{dR}(X)$.

Why is $\int_{Y} \phi = \int_{X} \eta_{Y} \wedge \phi$ ?

Comment: Do you mean $\phi \in H^{\color{red}k}_{\text{dR}}(X)$ and $\int_Y \phi = \int_X {\color{red}\eta_Y} \wedge \phi$?

Comment: This is basically the definition of Poincaré duality. What's more interesting is that if $\phi=\eta_Z$ for a codimension $k$ submanifold $Z$, then this integral computes the intersection number of $Y$ and $Z$. BTW, you need $X$ compact and oriented.

Comment: @Ted Shifrin I see, thank you very much.